# Ionic native app with user authentication(okta schematics)

Tags: okta

I am trying to make an ionic app with user authentication using okta OIDC app.  But when i am trying to login from the app using okta/login page in application, i am getting error in the console which reads: “refused to display {URL} in a frame because it set ‘x-frame-options’ to ‘sameorigin’”.  It's only happening when i trying to run app as Mobile App, as Web App it working fine.
I am using "oktadev/schematics" in ionic. Some related packages i am using are as follows:
ionic/angular : "^5.5.2",
angular/cli : "~12.1.1",
oktadev/schematics": "^5.1.1",
ionic-native/http : "5.36.0",
Node : 14.17.0,
Npm: 6.14.13
I would really appreciate if anyone could guide me in the right direction to solve this issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting

> "‘x-frame-options’ to ‘sameorigin’”

as error because mobile apps need to respect using the same origin http request. What you can do is add the domain from which data is being retrieved to your network_security_config.xml file.